# Using *ngIf causes infinite loop with HTTP request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, xmlhttprequest

```
private login() {
    this.http.get(`http://localhost/api/token/${id}`)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.response = res;
            if (this.response) {
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
            } else {
                console.log('access denied');
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

```
<p *ngIf="!login()">Wrong password or username</p>
```

Everything compiles correctly but when I just start the application, an infinite loop starts by sending hundreds of `access denied` logs to the console. This is unbelievable. `<p>` is visible on the screen.

Why does it happen? The login function is being called when `login` button is clicked. I don't have to click it to make the infinite loop start. It just happens when app appears in the browser.

Comment: maybe that `*ngIf` is residing within an `*ngFor` loop?

Comment: @5313M I dont think so mate

Comment: show some more code. you havn't mention from which component you are calling login. show your console.log(res); your routing file. you are calling a function when you don't return true or false it may be returning null or false so ! will turn it into true.

Comment: Why is that unbelievable? Angular has to keep calling that method to find out if it should still be showing the associated element. It will call the method every tick to see if it needs to update the state of the page.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i think you are right

Comment: @jonrsharpe Do you have some solution for me, mate? I have to show that paragraph when the `login()` returns false, somehow. And only then, when the `login()` function is executed. Not all the time.

Comment: @H.Doe do it the other way around; instead of the element calling the method directly, get the *component* to call the method and set a Boolean field (e.g. `userIsLoggedIn`) with the result. The element just uses that field: `<p *ngIf="!userIsLoggedIn" ...`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yep, thought the same thing but just hoped that this old solution would work somehow. Thanx m8

Answer (score 0):

The ngIf statement **periodically checks the status of the login's method** returned value: this is the reason why the login method is actually invoked n times. Instead of binding the ngIf to the login method's returned value, bind the statement to a boolean variable that is changed by the login method: this will prevent the method to be fired and the watcher will operate on the variable status. In example, in your controller...

```
public authError: boolean = false;

private _login() {
    this.http.get(`http://localhost/api/token/${id}`)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.response = res;
            if (this.response) {
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
            } else {
                console.log('access denied');
                // In case of error, set the auth error property to true
                this.authError = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

In your template:

```
<p *ngIf="authError">Wrong password or username</p>
```

Please notice that I changed the login method's name: private methods should start with an underscore by convention.